# C++ Modal dialog box continuing adding texts

Tags: c++, mfc

I have dialog box and in it, it has OK and Cancel buttons then it also has a ListBox to display text in two columns.  I would like to continue adding text into the ListBox after the dialog box is shown. How can I do that? Because after I call DoModal() to show the dialog box, the code does not continue to execute.  Or should I create two threads (one is display dialog box while another thread continues adding text to dialog box)?

Comment: Some more information about the library you are working with and what you've already tried would be helpful.

Comment: Tell us more about this application. Describe what should happen from the user's point of view. Where does this text that should be added to the listbox once the dialog is open come from ?

Comment: I plan to create a simple program to search for near by Bluetooth devices.    Whenever it detects BT device, it will update to the dialog box and user can select from it to pair.  The reason for this program because Microsoft BluetoothAPIs->BluetoothSelectDevices() does not work well on my machine when filtering out specific Bluetooth devices like either scanner or printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your dialog 'pull' the data it needs, maybe polling the data source with window messages every second, or every 100ms or so. Or, if you go the 'two threads' route (the better but more complicated option), have your data source post a window message to your dialog when there is new data, and then have the dialog fetch the data it needs. The reason for this is that it's much easier to use the existing CDialog infrastructure to get a window that behaves like an actual dialog, compared to building a modal window that acts like a dialog but isn't really.

If you do go the two threads route, your division of labor should be: one thread that does all the UI work (including showing the dialog), and one that 'generates' data and lets the UI know when there is new data. So the worker thread should not do anything related to the UI, nor call any methods on the dialog directly - you can't access windows from several threads. The only cross-thread window communication should happen through window message (i.e., use ::SendMessage()). So certainly *don't* do something like myDialog->m_theList.AddString("blah") from another thread, or something like it.

Comment: Thanks Roel.  I will use two threads to see how far I can go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Showing a dialog box modally halts further execution until you close the box.   Instead of showing it modal, show it normal but make it always on top so you can continue executing the code after the call to `DoModal()`.  Alternatively, populate the box with all the info it will need before you call `DoModal()`.

Comment: Thanks.  That is good suggestion, but it does not meet the requirements because I would like to continue feeding new text to dialog box whenever the incoming text is ready to display.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to take the "two threads" approach you will discover that the controls on MFC dialogs should not be updated or accessed from a thread other than the one that created the dialog.  Even if you have pointers to these controls available in another thread it is not thread-safe to access them.  This rule applies whether or not the dialog is modal.

Instead, your second thread would need to PostMessage or SendMessage to the dialog window, so the updates occur on the thread that created the dialog (most likely the main UI thread of the application).